# Multiple catalogs in Spark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am developing a PySpark application to be run on Databricks with Unity Catalog on, which means that all the tables I am reading will have a name like `catalog.database.table`. I am trying to figure out if I can activate multiple catalogs in unit tests too. I know there are workarounds I can use, such as allowing the prefix to the table to be configurable (e.g. in local unit tests read from `database.table`, on Databricks read from `catalog.database.table`), but it seems that open-source Spark 3.x should support multiple catalogs.

I am using pytest and defining the following fixture in `conftest.py`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark():
    builder = (
        SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp")
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
        .config(
            "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
        ).config(
            "spark.sql.catalog.my_catalog",
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
        )
    )

    spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
    yield spark
    spark.stop()
```

However if I try to use `my_catalog`:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def some_fixture(spark):
    spark.catalog.setCurrentCatalog("my_catalog")
    spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db")
```

I get a SparkException: `[INTERNAL_ERROR] The Spark SQL phase analysis failed with an internal error. You hit a bug in Spark or the Spark plugins you use. Please, report this bug to the corresponding communities or vendors, and provide the full stack trace.`

How do I use multiple catalogs in Spark?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer on this right now but I was experiencing this same issue while trying to setup a "local delta lake" for testing outside Databricks. I am using the Scala directly so I was able to jump down more into the code and see the bug is most likely a Delta issue. Multi-catalog support is rather new in Spark native so this might need to be adjusted for by Delta.

Here is the ticket I opened with them: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/2434